# Restarts to black screen after encountering unresponsive buttons in login UI with Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: system-installation, reboot

I just tried to install Ubuntu 13.10 on my old laptop using a DVD. During login, after asking for my email address and name, the "Register Later", "Back", and "Continue" buttons were not responding anymore.

So I restarted my laptop, but now I only have a black screen and a blinking cursor showing up after the ASUS screen. Neither <kbd>F12</kbd> nor inserting the DVD into the reader gets Ubuntu to reboot.

I had chosen the installation erasing my old Windows OS too, so I guess it erased Windows.

How can I install Ubuntu after these circumstances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into your BIOS/EUFI and make sure that your DVD drive is the first boot device, it sounds like your pc is going straight for your hard drive with the faulty ubuntu installation. Once you got the live dvd running reinstall Ubuntu.